# HighChart in ASP.NET MVC with Database connection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC and I attempting to display data from a database into a Highchart using Visual Studio 2015. I have the following code in my controller to get the data from the database:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Controllers
{
    public class SecondlyReadingDatasController : ApiController
    {

        private cloudsqlEntities db = new cloudsqlEntities();

        // GET: api/SecondlyReadingDatas
        public IQueryable<SecondlyReading> GetSecondlyReadings()
        {
            SecondlyReading sec = db.SecondlyReadings.First();
            return db.SecondlyReadings;
        }
```

This is my model:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class SecondlyReading
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ChannelID { get; set; }
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public double RMSVoltage { get; set; }
        public double Frequency { get; set; }
        public double RMSCurrent { get; set; }
        public double RealPower { get; set; }
        public double ReactivePower { get; set; }
        public double ApparentPower { get; set; }
        public double PowerFactor { get; set; }
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can get data in json format when I key in /api/SecondlyReadingDatas into my browser, however, my objective is to have that data to be plot into a line graph using high chart. I do know that something like the following code needs to be implemented to view the data in a line graph:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/TestWebsite/api/SecondlyReadingDatas',
  success: function(singleSeries) {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      series: [singleSeries]
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

I have also installed DotNet.HighChart in my project:

[image]

I have 2 main questions:

- Is there a difference downloading the Highchart library from the
  website, which will then be referenced in Visual Studio and
  installing DotNet.HighChart in Visual Studio itself?
- In which file do I place the `<script type="text/javascript">` ?
  Model, controller, or _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">` always placed in view - there in CSHTML file (usually in master layout page or `_Layout.cshtml`). I think there's no significant difference when either `DotNet.HighCharts` package or referencing `highcharts.js` library manually.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

`DotNet.HighCharts` package is includes `js` files that You can use them depending on the application.

[image: Highchart]

**Question 2**

You always should add `<script type="text/javascript">` in `View` (client side). `Model` and `Controller` are used for server side.

See [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1f3f2a/charting-in-mvc/) for more information about `Highcharts` in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: For view, are you referring to _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: @gram95 Yes. `_Layout.cshtml` is a `View`.

Comment: @gram95 Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.